# How do I attach an image to a Discord js v12 Embed?

Tags: node.js

Whenever I try to attach an image to a embed it does not appear!

```
    var captchaURL = new Discord.MessageAttachment(`./userCaptchas/${c.value}.bmp`, 'captchaurl.bmp');
    

    const cap = new Discord.MessageAttachment(captchaURL);
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Please Complete the captcha!')
    .attachFiles(captchaURL)
    .setImage('attachment://captchaurl.bmp')
    user.send(embed);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only set image-URLs as a parameter to `setImage()`
The easiest way of solving your problem would be to send your image into a discord-guild channel, copying the link of the image and then using that link as your parameter of the `.setImage()` method.

Consider having a look at this: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview